# How to run custom function by hovering or clicking on cell in google spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I need help to make a table which will have a cells as product thumbnails and by hovering or clicking on this small image, I want to show the pop up with big image of product.

(*Right now it works as hyperlink, but it is not enough*)

I know we have a few ways how to run function right now:

- from a custom spreadsheet function
- from a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) (from spreadsheet like on open, on edit or on form submit, or Time driven)
- from a custom menu (which must be created by e.g. on open)
- from a custom user interface (which must be created by e.g. on open)
- from a drawing or chart
- from the script editor

Is there any way how we can trigger event like hover or click on cell in table?

I have a few ideas right now :

- Some how place big image in comment or note in cell.
- Make a custom function which will return image/chart/drawing as a value and apply function for this image/chart/drawing. But seems we should have much more easy way to do it =)

I know this is a similar question as: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740798/tooltip-image-on-cell-hover-google-spreadsheet) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727266/how-to-run-javascript-byc-clicking-a-cell-in-google-sheets) but they are old and google has made an API update since December 11, 2014.

Answer (score 0):

- Add an Image ( Insert > Image ) to your sheet.
- Resize and Move it to fit your needs.
- Click the drop-down symbol in the upper right corner of the image.
- Select 'Assign Script'
- Enter the name of the script you wish to run.

Comment: I have around 1000 products I should create image 1000 times?