# Recording when a hyperlink is used in a google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, onclick, timestamp

Is it possible to record when a user clicks on a hyperlink in a cell, such as adding a timestamp to another cell?

I've done some looking and all sources I've seen say that this is an onclick event, which isn't possible to record in google sheets.

Comment: Only click event you can track inside worksheet is click on image, [how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37130817) - this can be start point for workaround

Comment: The problem with images is that they're not actually connected to cells. They're just placed on the spreadsheet. So I think the best answer to your question is no.  Also I don't think there is a way to programatically  setup the connection from the image click to the script. You might consider displaying your products on a dialog then you could capture the onclick event for a given text area and use javascript and google.script.run to record the click on a spread sheet or datafile.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to track click on arbitrary links in Google Sheets cells as one Google Apps Script there isn't a on click trigger.